# Did chekitana survive the Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, war

I have seen lists of Pandava survivors in which he isn't listed.  Did he die or did he leave the war before the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chekitana did not survive the war. He was killed by Duryodhana on the last day of the war.

> O monarch, thy warriors headed by Duryodhana rushed against the Pandavas. Beholding the Kaurava host, the sons of Pandu, with leonine roars, rushed against those warriors headed by Duryodhana. Then thy son, O bull of Bharata's race, singling out Chekitana amongst those rushing heroes, pierced him deeply with a lance in the chest. Chekitana amongst those rushing heroes, **pierced him deeply with a lance in the chest. Thus assailed by thy son, Chekitana fell down on the terrace of his car**, covered with blood, and overcome with a deep swoon. Beholding Chekitana slain, the great car-warriors among the Pandavas incessantly poured their arrowy showers (upon the Kauravas).
>
> [Shalya Parva Chapter 12](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09012.htm)